# How to subtract/add time from a csv column in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, csv, timezone

I'm new to python/programming and haven't dealt with time yet. I have a csv file with a column of time/date information but in the wrong time zone. How can I subtract or add hours? It's formatted like this:

```
1 Jan 2014 hh:mm
```

If it helps I've already broken down the data into a list of dicts:

```
[{datetime: 1 Jan 2014 00:00}, {datetime: 2 Jan 2014 00:01}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create datetime objects and use [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to add  hours/days etc..

```
d = {"datetime": "2 Jan 2014 00:01"}
from datetime import datetime ,timedelta

print(datetime.strptime(d["datetime"],"%d %b %Y %H:%M")+timedelta(hours=4))
2014-01-02 04:01:00
```